# Simpson's Composite Rule GUI

Tags: matlab

I got this problem while doing the Simpson's composite rule

> Attempted to access funcion(1.2); index must be a positive integer or logical.
>
> Error in Simpson_Comp>Calcular_Callback (line 185)
>      sum_even = sum_even + funcion(x(i)); "

```
funcion=get(handles.funcion,'string');

 b=str2num(get(handles.b,'string'));
 a=str2num(get(handles.a,'string'));
 n=str2num(get(handles.n,'string'));
 h = (b-a)/n;

sum_even = 0;

for i = 1:n/2-1
   x(i) = a + 2*i*h;
   sum_even = sum_even + funcion(x(i));
end

sum_odd = 0;

for i = 1:n/2
   x(i) = a + (2*i-1)*h;
   sum_odd = sum_odd + funcion(x(i));
end

integral = h*(funcion(a)+ 2*sum_even + 4*sum_odd +funcion(b))/3
 fprintf('el valor aproximado de la integral es: %10.15f\n\n',integral);

 set(handles.solucion,'string',num2str(integral));
```

I'm testing it with `x^2` and `[0,3]`

I don't know why `x(i)` must be an integer ?

Comment: How are you defining `funcion`?

Comment: I mean, I am entering as a string, but obviously then i put in to a integer. But i don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because `handles.funcion` is a string but you are assuming that it's an actual function - as noted in your comments.  Therefore, MATLAB is interpreting this as indexing into a string.  Try doing using the [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) which converts a string to a function handle that is defined by the contents of that string.  Also, because `str2func` accepts in a string that is formatted like an anonymous function, you need to prepend `@(x)` before the actual string.

As such, either add this into your string in your GUI widget, or prepend the string once you grab the string after the capture event triggers.

Let's do the second way because I'm assuming you don't want the user to type in more text than they need to.  Therefore, after your `get` call, use `str2func`:

```
funcion=get(handles.funcion,'string');
funcion = str2func(['@(x)' funcion]); %// New
```

Comment: Hello, I did that and, I am having this problem:

Warning: The input to STR2FUNC "x^2" is not a valid function name. This will generate an error in a future release. 
> In Simpson_Comp>Calcular_Callback at 175
  In gui_mainfcn at 96
  In Simpson_Comp at 42
  In @(hObject,eventdata)Simpson_Comp('Calcular_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Undefined function 'x^2' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @CarlosMartínez you need to use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) with `str2func`. e.g. `handles.funcion = '@(x)x^2'; funcion = str2func(handles.funcion); funcion(3)`

Comment: ¿But How do i do that for a GUI?

Comment: @CarlosMartínez rather than typing `'x^2'` into your edit box, you type `'@(x)x^2'`. Or, if you're feeling adventurous, just prepend `'@(x)'` to the string: `funcion=['@(x)' get(handles.funcion,'string')];`

Comment: EDIT, I checked an haven't done: `funcion = str2func(funcion);` again

Comment: @excaza - Thanks for the spot.  I thought the OP was already doing that.  I'll edit my post.